# OpenSSH server refuses to accept key authentication

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I tried to use public key authentication on my new server, and I came across this problem.

```
$ ssh -v -i .ssh/server 192.168.1.100
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data .ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.100 [192.168.1.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/server type -1
debug1: identity file .ssh/server-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '192.168.1.100' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in .ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: .ssh/server
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

and then I have to input my password to get logged  in.

But, if I already have one session connected to that server (which is connected by password), then the following connection uses key auth to avoid password input.

If there is no SSH connection already established, I can't connect without input password.

This is really weird to me, I checked the MD5 of `/usr/sbin/sshd` between the new server and the other normal server, it's the same. Then I just copied the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` from the other normal server to the new server, and ran `service ssh restart`. The problem still exists.

How am I supposed to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

Check that your `.ssh` folder and the files inside it on the client machine are only readable by the owner (`chmod -R 600 .ssh`) and that the owner is correct for the folder and files (use `chown` command if necessary).

Also check the `authorized_keys` folder and file on the server (probably in `/root/.ssh` or the home folder of the user trying to login) to make sure their permissions and owner are set in the same way.

---

Edit: based on more feedback (and some guesswork!) - can you check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and see whether the following parameter is set like below. If not, try editing it.

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /home/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Note, this assumes you don't login remotely as root

Comment: my .ssh is 700 and files in .ssh is 600, and I double checked ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in remote machine. Setup public key auth is the first thing I do after I install the system, so it's not likely to be messed up by other operation. btw, problem still..

Comment: OK - I am adding something to my answer based on this.

Comment: there is a line of "#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys". I tried comment it out, but of no use.. btw, the same '/usr/sbin/sshd' with the same 'sshd_config', how the they behave differently?

Comment: Finally I reinstalled ubuntu, then I set up openssh-server in one minute and it working fine now... Still don't know what's wrong. :(

Comment: Sometimes it is really difficult to find out what's the problem. I once mispelled authorized_keys as auhorized_keys. I needed about one hour to troubleshoot this. Did you see the mispelling? It is really tricky! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Remember to run `service ssh restart` to apply the changes.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the permissions on the home directory were `775` instead of `0755` or lower.

The entire path to authorized_keys file, i.e. `/home/user/.ssh/` must be `0755` or lower.

Comment: THANK YOU This just got read of a headache I've had for a week now. Most people only mention the .ssh folder (700) and the authorized_keys (600)

Comment: Same, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

I fixed my own case of this error by removing `id_rsa.pub` from .ssh.

I had copied `id_rsa` from another machine and distributed it across several dummy clients. Therefore, `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` were actually different keys which prevented the usage of `id_rsa` altogether.

No error message to clearly indicate this though. I figured it out essentially by accident, trying to get the different machines into an identical state.

Answer (score 3):

From my finding, the least permission of the target's home director is `750`. If the world's bit is not `0`, it will not work.

Eg. for root's directory:

```
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Jul 20 11:57 root
```

Next is `/root/.ssh`

```
drwx------  2 root root  4096 Jul 17 03:28 .ssh
```

Then `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
-rw------- 1 root root 1179 Jul 17 03:28 authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 2):

After troubling a lot I got the solution of the problem:

Home directory of the user should not have permission `777` or world writable. If it is the case, SSH key verification will fail and you have to put password for login.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the account you are trying to ssh to is a user with a password on the remote server. I just banged my head on the wall for half an hour before finding this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14421105/758174

Answer (score 1):

If your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has the following line un-commented, then your SSH configuration only allows a fixed list of users to ssh into the system, and you need to add any new accounts to the list:

```
AllowUsers root user1 user2 user3
```

Any other users than the ones listed above trying to login via SSH would receive this cryptic error messages:

```
Roaming not allowed by server
```

Answer (score 1):

i've been struggling with this for ... months.
Now i've figured out that it's due to StrictModes . You must defined **StrictModes no**

Here's the remote host side's :
/etc/ssh/sshd_config file

- RSAAuthentication yes
- PubkeyAuthentication yes
- AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
- ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
- PasswordAuthentication yes
- UsePAM no
- StrictModes no

Answer (score 0):

I found out that after changing my user and group name (but not IDs) in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`, but forgetting to change `/etc/shadow` accordingly, I got the same "No roaming allowed" message.